# Menu siding from top and push the page down

Tags: javascript, css, menu

I need some help please.

I'm trying to make a menu that pushes the page down when clicked and displays the specific sub-menu.

The menu should be above the page with a height of 50px. If i'm using height the content won't be pushed down.

When I click on first link i should get the sub menu for that link. If I push the second link the first submenu should be replaced with the second set of sub menu links.

Right now it's all messed up and I cant get it to work. I dont know much about javascript, as you can see here:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery(".menu-item-has-children").click(function(){
        jQuery(this).children(".sub-menu").slideToggle();
    });
});
```

Thank you in advance for all your time.

https://jsfiddle.net/tjkr6L08/

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at https://jsfiddle.net/tjkr6L08/1/

Javascript

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery(".menu-item-has-children").click(function() {

    jQuery(".opened").slideUp().removeClass("opened");
    jQuery(this).children(".sub-menu").slideToggle().addClass("opened");

  });
});
```

CSS

```
.sub-menu {
  display: none;
  position:absolute;
  top:40px;
  left:0;
  right:0;
}
```

So your issue is 50% css, 50% javascript. What you want is to make a reference to previously opened submenu, so you can close it. To make things align properly, the menu can be absolute;

So the above is the quickest possible solution - might not be the best, but will give you an idea how to proceed.

Comment: thank you for your fast response but i'm getting more confused now.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the bootstrap collapse class instead of toggle in java script once see the documentation of the bootstrap [Collapse](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/collapse/)

```css
  .menu-menu-top-container {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  position: static;
  height: 50px;
}

.menu-top li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding:5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="menu-top">
  <div class="menu-menu-top-container">
    <ul id="menu-menu-top" class="menu">
      <li><a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#Companie">Companie</a>
      <li><a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#Cariere"> Cariere</a>
       <li id="menu-item-457" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-457"><a href="contact/index.html">Contact</a></li>
 </ul>

  <div id="Companie" class="collapse">
      <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li id="menu-item-450" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-450"><a href="companie/echipa-copy/index.html">Echipa</a></li>
          <li id="menu-item-451" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-451"><a href="companie/echipa/index.html">Echipa</a></li>
          <li id="menu-item-452" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-452"><a href="companie/implicare-sociala/index.html">Implicare socială</a></li>
          <li id="menu-item-453" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-453"><a href="companie/misiune-valori/index.html">Misiune și Valori</a></li>
          <li id="menu-item-454" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-454"><a href="companie/calitate-si-certificari/index.html">Calitate și certificări</a></li>
          <li id="menu-item-455" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-455"><a href="companie/despre-noi/index.html">Despre noi?</a></li>
        </ul>
  </div>
  <div  id="Cariere" class="collapse">
   <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li id="menu-item-450" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-450"><a href="companie/echipa-copy/index.html">Echipa Copy</a></li>
          <li id="menu-item-451" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-451"><a href="companie/echipa/index.html">Echipa</a></li>
          <li id="menu-item-452" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-452"><a href="companie/implicare-sociala/index.html">Implicare socială</a></li>
          <li id="menu-item-453" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-453"><a href="companie/misiune-valori/index.html">Misiune și Valori</a></li>
          <li id="menu-item-454" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-454"><a href="companie/calitate-si-certificari/index.html">Calitate și certificări</a></li>
          <li id="menu-item-455" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-455"><a href="companie/despre-noi/index.html">Despre noi?</a></li>
        </ul>
  </div>
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If I remove the height:50px it pushes the menu just fine. And how can I close the sub-menu when I push the link from the menu again or if i click another link should be replaced with his sub menu.

Comment: is there any way to do this without bootstrap? it looks like a simple code and i cant get to the bottom of it.